# populate dropdown using the response from Ajax POST call

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to make two dependent dropdowns. And I'm using PHP commands to get all the data values from an API.
Now I have been able to populate the first dropdown but then for the second dropdown I am making an Ajax POST call since I need to use a PHP function
Here's the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('select#district_area').change(function(){
          var district_val = $(this).val();
          console.log(district_val);
          $.ajax({
              url:"c.php",
              method: "POST",
              data: {'district_val':district_val},
              success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
               $('select#district_area').html(data);
            }
          });
          
      });
  });
</script>
<body>
<div>
<select name="district_area" id="district_area">
<option> Select District </option>
<?php foreach($districts as $first){ ?>
         <option><?php print($first['district_name']); ?></option>
         <?php } ?>
</select>
<p></p>
<select name="delivery_area" id="delivery_area">
<option>Select Delivery Area</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
```

Here $districts is the array of values.

`c.php`:

```
$district_value = $_POST['district_val'];
$del_val = search_recursive_key_value($decoded, 'name', $district_value);   
?>
<select name="delivery_area" id="delivery_area">
<option><?php echo $del_val; ?></option>
</select>
```

The Ajax POST call works. The response I get is not in JSON format. I've been trying to get it in JSON format using `dataType:"JSON"` but it still doesn't return it in JSON and so I'm not being able to make the second dependent dropdown.

I've console logged it

The response:
[image]

How do I populate a dropdown using these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the HTML tags for generating options and append them to select dropdown.

Try something like this in your success function in AjaxCall:

```
$("select#delivery_area").append('<option value=' + "data.district_val" + '>' + data.district_val + '</option>');
```

If your data length is more than one, then you need a for loop to generate each options and append each one to select dropdown.

Comment: It worked. I was able to use a `for` loop and populate the second dropdown. Thanks a lot @StevenXXCCC

Comment: No problem, Glad my answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

not too sure what you are trying to do.. maybe this will help:

```
$('select#district_area').html(data);
```

should be

```
$('select#delivery_area').html(data);
```

Comment: there are two dropdowns. The first one's tagged #district_area and the second one's tagged #delivery_area.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('select#district_area').change(function(){
          var district_val = $(this).val();
          console.log('District selected:',district_val);
          $("select#delivery_area").empty();
          $.ajax({
              url:"c.php",
              method: "POST",
              data: {'district_val' : district_val},
              success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                splitData = data.split(",");
                console.log(splitData);
                for(var i=0; i<splitData.length-1; i++){
                  $("select#delivery_area").append('<option value="">' + splitData[i] + '</option>')
                }
              }
          });
      });
    });
```